# Generator of limits of successions according to type of indeterminacy. Correct syntax

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, export, programming, syntax, code-generation

I am trying to make a limit generator with 3 columns, number of the exercise, the second column is the limit (perfectly written with n-->00), and the third column is the result of the limit.
I have seen some help in the forum and in the MMA help some more tips to move forward but without results (Limits must be results without using l'Hôpital's Rule)

For each indeterminacy it should generate 25 random limits that meet that indeterminacy
to export it to a pdf.
The way I turned out can be changed for a better one is what occurred to me, can you give me a hand

The picture gives an idea of ​​what I'm looking for.
[image]

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
(* Generator of exercises of limits of sequences*)
indeterminaciones = {Tooltip["Indeterminación 1", "Forma 0/0"], 
Tooltip["Indeterminación 2", "Forma \[Infinity]/\[Infinity]"], 
Tooltip["Indeterminación 3", "Forma 0*\[Infinity]"], 
Tooltip["Indeterminación 4", "Forma \[Infinity]-\[Infinity]"], 
Tooltip["Indeterminación 5", "Forma 1^\[Infinity]"], 
Tooltip["Indeterminación 6", "Forma 0^0"], 
Tooltip["Indeterminación 7", "Forma \[Infinity]^0"]};
Manipulate[
TableForm[
Table[{i, TraditionalForm[Limit[expr, x -> a]], 
TraditionalForm[Limit[expr, x -> a] // Evaluate]}, {i, 1, 25}], 
TableHeadings -> {None, {"Numeración", "Límite", 
 "Resultado"}}], {{indeterminacion, 
 Tooltip["Indeterminación 1", "Forma 0/0"]}, 
indeterminaciones}, {{expr, x^2 + 3 x - 2}, InputField}, {{a, 0}, 
InputField}]
```

Comment: [`ClearAll`](https://reference.wolframcloud.com/cloudplatform/ref/ClearAll.html) requires an argument; otherwise it does nothing. I moved it to the first line of your code.

Comment: @creidhne,Nothing appears in the display, there should be 25 limits of a type of intertermination of sequences when n->00 but all different, nothing appears, something is more in my code and I don't know what it is